# Angular and WebAPI configuration

Tags: c#, angular, azure, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.6

We have an Angular 4 app and a WebAPI app (.NET Framework).  We have an Azure application set up with both apps deployed to it (client and service).  The root path points to the client.

The HTTP Requests to our API (/api/{controller}/) are not reaching our service and it looks like instead the Angular route is picking them up and returning the index.html as the response content.

How can we set up Azure so that our Angular application serves up the HTML/CSS/JS content and any call to "/api/" routes to our service?

We have tried having the root path point to the service, but we then receive a 404 for all non-API requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I needed to serve up static files as outlined in this article:

https://mirkomaggioni.com/2016/09/11/owin-middleware-for-static-files/

In a nutshell, I deployed the service (WebAPI) to the Azure root and the client (Angular 4) deployed as the compiled "dist" folder.

I added the following NuGet packages:

```
<package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net462" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.FileSystems" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net462" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net462" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net462" />
```

Then created an OWIN Startup class that looks like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var physicalFileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(@"./dist");
        var options = new FileServerOptions
        {
            EnableDefaultFiles = true,
            FileSystem = physicalFileSystem
        };
        options.StaticFileOptions.FileSystem = physicalFileSystem;
        options.StaticFileOptions.ServeUnknownFileTypes = true;
        options.DefaultFilesOptions.DefaultFileNames = new[]
        {
            "index.html"
        };

        app.UseFileServer(options);
    }
}
```