# How to host Angular application with WebApi 2 c# in IIS?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api

I have an Angular project and an WebApi 2 project in c#, i need to deploy both projects under the same solution in **IIS**, the Angular app makes calls to WebApi.

After reading some other similar questions i've tryed to add the WebApi 2 application as WebSite application in IIS by giving it alias "api" and by removing path 'api" from controllers.

Then in the main website i just put all files from dist folder.

The problem is that when only the API are hosted, i'm able to make calls to it, but when i host the Angular app any request to the API are declined and it's like the Angular app routes all requests..

So when the Angular app is hosted as website and API as it's application any request to API gives Error 404.

I hadn't touched the web.config and any other configuration file of Angular project so all values are set by default.

So the question is:

**How could i host Angular App and WebApi 2 in the same IIS Web Site?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular and WebAPI configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45179678/angular-and-webapi-configuration)